# How to open CSV file in R when R says "no such file or directory"?

Tags: r

I have an excel file that I want to open in R. I tried both of these commands after saving the excel file as a csv file or a text file.

read.table() or read.csv()

I think part of the problem is where the file is located. I have it saved on the desk top. What am I missing here?

Here is the R output

```
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'Rtrial.csv': No such file or directory
> help.search("read.csv")
> read.csv("Rtrial.csv")
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'Rtrial.csv': No such file or directory
> read.table("tab")
```

Comment: It would in general be useful to provide more information; in this particular case it's hard to make a truly reproducible example, but you could at least show the full command you tried, and the output of getwd() [i.e., show your working directory]

Comment: for general advice of opening excel files (xls, xlsx), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099243/read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-r-script/6100369#6100369

Comment: You're trying to open a file assuming it's in the working directory. On the other hand You mentioned the file is saved in Desktop folder, right? Is Your working directory Desktop? As @BenBolker wrote, provide more information

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To throw out another option, why not set the working directory (preferably via a script) to the desktop using `setwd('C:\John\Desktop')` and then read the files just using file names

Comment: +1: this is a great idea; if you change your directory structure then all that needs to change is this one line.

Comment: Still not clear to me why the original poster was getting a permissions error in one of the iterations, then ...

Comment: for unix based, should be like this ```setwd("~/dir")```.

Answer (score 23):

Try

```
f <- file.choose()
```

to choose the file interactively and save the name in `f`.

Then run `read.csv` on the saved filename

```
d <- read.csv(f)
```

Comment: But then you have to choose the file manually every time you run the script.

Comment: True.  This is more useful for exploratory analysis than scripting.  It also can help to figure out the proper name and path of a file, which can then be written out as in Benjamin's answer.

Answer (score 14):

Sound like you just have an issue with the path. Include the full path, if you use backslashes they need to be escaped: `"C:\\folder\\folder\\Desktop\\file.csv"` or `"C:/folder/folder/Desktop/file.csv"`.

```
myfile = read.csv("C:/folder/folder/Desktop/file.csv")  # or read.table()
```

It may also be wise to avoid spaces and symbols in your file names, though I'm fairly certain spaces are OK.

Comment: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Documents and Settings\Manley\Desktop': Permission denied
>

Comment: @illbill: Now it seems to be a permissions issue. Is it read only? Do you have read rights?

Comment: @Svun is probablity right. R won't read the file if it is already open in Excel.

Answer (score 9):

I had to combine Maiasaura and Svun answers to get it to work: using setwd and escaping all the slashes and spaces.

```
setwd('C:\\Users\\firstname\ lastname\\Desktop\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3')
data = read.csv("file.csv")
data
```

This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way to do it. It uses the ability of R to construct file paths based on the platform and hence will work on both Mac OS and Windows. Moreover, you don't need to convert your xls file to csv, as there are many R packages that will help you read xls directly (e.g. gdata package).

```
# get user's home directory
home = setwd(Sys.getenv("HOME"));

# construct path to file
fpath = file.path(home, "Desktop", "RTrial.xls");

# load gdata library to read xls files
library(gdata);

# read xls file
Rtrial = read.xls(fpath);
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: On WinXP (and possibly other Windows) the `HOME` environment variable points to `My Documents`, and the desktop is in the parent of that folder.  You either need `Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE")` if it exists, or `paste(Sys.getenv("HOMEDRIVE"), Sys.getenv("HOMEPATH"), sep = "")`.

Comment: @Richie. Thanks for the pointer. I use Mac OS, so was assuming that HOME would point to the parent of desktop.

Comment: On the mac HOME points to your /Users folder (usually this is your name), so yes, this is the parent folder of the Desktop

Answer (score 4):

1. Save as in excel will keep the file open and lock it so you can't open it.  Close the excel file or you won't be able to use it in R.
2. Give the full path and escape backslashes `read.csv("c:\\users\\JoeUser\\Desktop\\JoesData.csv")`

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced that this error occurs when you either move the excel file to the destination other than where your r file is located or when you move your r file to the destination other than where your excel file is located.

**Good Practice:**

1. Keep your .r and .csv files in the same directory.
2. open your .r file from getting into its directory instead of opening the r file from  rstuio's open file option.

*You also have **import Dataset option** at **Environment Block**, just click there and get your required packages installed & from next time use this option to read datasets. You will not get this error again.
I also appreciate the above provided answers.*

[image]

Comment: Yes. Even if the working directory is set to where the csv file is located; as long as the R/Rmd file is NOT in that directory, it will not find the csv.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of reading Excel including the new format xlsx could be the package speedR (https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/speedr/). It is an interactive and visual data importer. Besides importing you can filter(subset) the existing objects from the R workspace.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was very simple, the working directory was not the "Source" directory that was printed when the file ran. To fix this, you can use `getwd()` and `setwd()` to get your relative links working, or just use a full path when opening the csv.

```
print(getwd()) # Where does the code think it is?
setwd("~/Documents") # Where do I want my code to be?
dat = read.csv("~/Documents/Data Visualization/expDataAnalysis/one/ac1_survey.csv") #just make it work!
```

Answer (score 0):

MAC OS It happened to me as well. I simply chose from the R toolbar MISC and then chose Change Working Directory. I was able to choose the directory that the .csv file was saved in.  When I went back to the command line and typed getwd() the full directory was updated and correct and the read.csv function finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and when I checked the properties of the file on file explorer, it shows me the next message:

"Security: This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer"

You click on the "Unblock" button and... you can access to the file from R without any problem, just using read.csv() function and from the directory specified as your working directory, even if is not the same as the file’s directory you are accessing to.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and I first switched to another directory and then switched back and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me, accesing data from root. use double slash to access address.

```
dataset = read.csv('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Machine Learning\\Data.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Kindly check whether the file name has an extension for example:

   ```
   abc.csv
   ```

   if so remove the `.csv` extension.
2. set `wd` to the folder containing the file `(~)`
3. `data<-read.csv("abc.csv")`

Your data has been read the data object

Answer (score 0):

In my case this very problem was raised by wrong spelling, lower case 'c:' instead of upper case 'C:' in the path. I corrected spelling and problem vanished.

Answer (score 0):

You can add absolute path to the file

```
heisenberg <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/tiago/Desktop/sample_100000.csv")
```

If really want to run something like

```
heisenberg <- read.csv(file="sample_100000.csv")
```

then you'll have to change the working directory to match the place the .CSV file is at. [More about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58685227/5675325).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with the same csv file and the same script I used till the previous day. I found two solutions:

1. rename the file (I just added a "1" at the end of the name
2. open the file (I did it with Excel) and save it with another name