# R tool Reading a text file shows Error,

Tags: r

This is my question 
  if i input this to my R data Mining tool

```
mydata <- read.csv("filename.txt")
```

it will shows an error like below

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'filename.txt': No such file or directory
```

what can i do to clear this error

Comment: try to give full path like c://abce//thk//filename.tx

Comment: @Devi Ganesh.  Do you have the file in the working directory? check `getwd()` and also `list.files()`.  If the file is in other directory, `setwd(path_to_file)` is one option or use `read.csv(file.choose())`

Comment: Have you done any searching? A quick glance throws up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568847/how-to-open-csv-file-in-r-when-r-says-no-such-file-or-directory http://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_anybody_explain_why_R_cannot_read_a_certain_file

Answer (score 0):

Use read.delim("Path of the file like C://Users//Desktop//filename.txt")

which has more options than read.csv