# Error message setwd()

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, setwd

I had to reset up my computer and changed to Ubuntu. 
Version 1.0.136 – © 2009-2016 RStudio, Inc.
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
RStudio Safari/538.1 Qt/5.4.0

Before I used:

Version 0.99.903 – © 2009-2016 RStudio, Inc.
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
rstudio Safari/538.1 Qt/5.4.1

Unfortunately within my R Studio I am facing following issue using an RMD file:

1. Setting a working directory gives following issue:
   The working directory was changed to ... inside a notebook chunk. The working directory will be reset when the chunk is finished running. Use the knitr root.dir option in the setup chunk to change the the working directory for notebook chunks.
2. Within my existing working directory i cannot open my csv file. 
   kann Datei 'ClimateChangeTabbedExtractcc14.1.csv' nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefundenFehler in file(file, "rt") : kann Verbindung nicht öffnen

Translation: Cannot open file 'ClimateChangeTabbedExtractcc14.1.csv'. File or directory not found in file(file „rt“) : cannot open connection.
This error message is slightly confusing, as dir() showed my that the file exists in the current directory.

Does anyone know the solution? My approach would be to change my R version to 0.99.903.

Thanks for your support.
Nils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's a permission issue, or if not a path issue. Could you provide some code? Also you might like to have a look at  this thread: [Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466317/error-in-filefile-rt-cannot-open-the-connection)

Comment: Hi Tina, thanks the first issue was a permission issue. The second issue resulted from non interpretable signs in the file.

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it sorted :)