# I cannot stitch a markdown in R, receiving and error; how can I solve this? UPDATE:

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am trying to stitch an R Markdown and I am running in to the following error message:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
3.file(file, "rt")
2.read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)
1.read.csv("~/Desktop/GOVT 300/leaders.csv")
```

I have tried using:

```
{r}
setwd("~/Documents/GOVT 300")
leaders.csv <- read.csv("~/Desktop/GOVT 300/leaders.csv")
```

but this has not worked to my avail. How can I solve this issue?

Update: Thank you for the input, I was able to fix that issue but have bumped into another one. I am receiving this error:

`Line 43: Error in ifelse(leader$result == level[1] | leaders$result == level[2] | : object 'level' not found Calls: <Anonymous>... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> ifelse Execution halted`

My code on line 43 in as follows:

`leaders$result <- as.factor(leaders$result)`

The affected chunk is:

````
```{r}

leaders$result <- as.factor(leaders$result)

leaders$success <- ifelse(leaders$result == level[1] | leaders$result == level[2] | leaders$result==level[3] | leaders$result==level[4], 1,0)

levels(leaders$result)

mean(leaders$success)

```
````

Comment: You could try passing the full path explicitly to `read.csv`, without messing about with `setwd`

Comment: This could be one of several things, including: file permissions, file locked by another process (e.g., Excel), or as others have suggested, location or spelling of the filename.

Comment: You can always test with `file.exists("~/Desktop/GOVT 300/leaders.csv")` first to verify it's there and rule out a problem with spelling and location.

Comment: I fixed with: ```setwd("~/Documents/GOVT 300/.")
leaders<-read.csv("~/Documents/GOVT 300/leaders.csv")``` Now, I have run into another error:


```Line 43: Error in ifelse(leader$result == level[1] | leaders$result == level[2] | : object 'level' not found Calls: <Anonymous>... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> ifelse Execution halted```

Comment: @IanChamberlin ; well that seems to be saying that it can't find the object level - but we dont know as we can't see the actual code. I'd suggest that you write your code in a normal R file and edit it when you get an error. When your script is error free create an rmarkdown file.

Comment: There is still no `level` in your example - but taking a punt, do you mean 
`ifelse(leaders$result == levels(leaders$result)[1] |` etc? If so, you may be able to write it as `ifelse(leaders$result %in% levels(leaders$result)[1:4], 1, 0)`, or more succinctly `as.integer(leaders$result %in% levels(leaders$result)[1:4])`

Comment: Please don't change gthe question/add questions after you post ... instead start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two `GOVT 300` folder, one in Documents and other in Desktop you should try what [@user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452099/i-cannot-stitch-a-markdown-in-r-receiving-and-error-how-can-i-solve-this#comment91847624_52452099) suggests. If it is not the case, be sure where the `leaders.csv` file is. In R

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

usually means path problems. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466317/error-in-filefile-rt-cannot-open-the-connection) for more details.

Comment: I did that, I now have the working directory set and have run into another error. The error being:

Line 43: Error in ifelse(leader$result == level[1] | leaders$result == level[2] | : object 'level' not found Calls: <Anonymous>... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> ifelse Execution halted

Comment: Ok, then I recommend you to update your original question with this new error.

Comment: what's the output of `head(leaders.csv)`? and what is `level` ? a vector, list...

Comment: Fabio, I recently updated the question. I am relatively new to R, thank you for the input. Please see my updates, i hope they help you to help me.

Comment: No problem, but I still need to know what is the `level` object as well as  see how R opened your file with the output of `head(leaders.csv)`.