# Directory path for R source script within markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I have a `county data.R` script where I am creating my primary df and a `methods.Rmd` where I would like to use that df. I would like to use the relative paths from my project and the `getwd()` confirmed the path, instead of creating a working directory like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466317/error-in-filefile-rt-cannot-open-the-connection), and it was correct. I was largely working off [this tutorial](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/07/09/making-use-of-external-r-code-in-knitr-and-r-markdown/). What am I missing here?

That script begins by loading the root data using the following.

**county data.R**

```
# read file
tf <- read.delim('data/cdc/suicide2017.txt')
```

If I run `county data.R` script by itself, `tf` is created fine. If I run the following in `methods.Rmd` I get an error.

**methods.Rmd**

````
```{r}
source('./county data.R')
source('./reference.R')

head(tf)```
````

Error:

```
cannot open file './data/cdc/suicide2017.txt': No such file or directoryError in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

**EDIT:**
Directory structure

```
-myproject
-r/
--scripts/
---county data.R
---methods.Rmd
-data/
--cdc/
---suicide2017.txt
```

Comment: If the file you read is placed in a path diverging from the parent directory (i.e. parent to the folder containing `methods.Rmd`), try `tf <- read.delim(file.path(getwd(), "../data/cdc/suicide2017.txt"))`. Go up two or more dir levels by adding `../` for each level.

Comment: @Luminita Added directory for clarification. So would the correct syntax in `methods.Rmd` be `source('../r/scripts/county data.R')` Or do I need to change syntax in `county data.R`

Comment: The `country_data.R` is sourced correctly. Within the script `country_data.R` I would  read `suicide2017.txt` as: `tf <- read.delim(file.path(getwd(), "../../data/cdc/suicide2017.txt"))`.

Comment: Tried that and got: `cannot open file './county data.R': No such file or directoryError in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection`

Comment: I find this strange. When knitting the Rmd, the current working dir is set to the folder where the Rmd file is found. `source('./county data.R')` should work fine (from your question it seems it gets sourced correctly as the Error you indicate corresponds to a line of code from `county_data.R`. But according to the comment above it seems it stopped working. I wouldn't expect the solution you provide in the answer below to work. Did you in the meantime set another working directory in the .Rmd file before sourcing `county data.R`?

Comment: Also, I realized that `getwd()` from  `file.path(getwd(), "../../data/cdc/suicide2017.txt")` is redundant. `file.path("../../data/cdc/suicide2017.txt")` should normally work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Luminita for directing me, I was one level too short. Posting answer in case someone in the future is as dumb as me.

**methods.Rmd** should be:

`source('r/scripts/county data.R')`