# Error in py_run_file_impl: System Exit: No such file or directory

Tags: python, r, shiny, shiny-server, reticulate

I'm trying to run `Task1.py` via Shiny framework of `R` in `Task1.r`. Python code is successfully running. But it is giving me error in some line.

***Task1.py:***

```
   ...
    ... 
   params.override(...) //This line is running fine and giving desired output
   params.process()  //This line is giving error that file doesn't exists
    ...
   ...
```

***Task1.r:***

```
observeEvent(input$action_retrain_1,{
...
 ...                
py_run_file("D:/..../Task1.py")
 ...
...
  })
```

***Previously asked question that I'm following to resolve error:***

[How to open CSV file in R when R says "no such file or directory"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568847/how-to-open-csv-file-in-r-when-r-says-no-such-file-or-directory)

***Effort to resolve error:***

I used following two lines before `py_run_file()`, but it is still giving me same error. What should I do? What am I missing?

```
setwd('D:/PycharmProjects/.../sample')
myfile = read.csv('D:/PycharmProjects/.../sample/parameters.yaml')
```

***Error:***

```
Warning: Error in py_run_file_impl: SystemExit: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/PycharmProjects/.../sample/parameters.yaml'
  76: <Anonymous>
```

`parameters.yaml` file exists in folder named sample, but I don't know why it is giving me error. I'm running this in Pycharm, there it works well. But it is giving me problem in `R`. Anyone know how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: try adding // instead of / in paths

Comment: @dilkash nothing worked with this.